# Assets not loaded when using CloudFlare SSL

Tags: http, ssl, https, cloudflare

I recently installed SSL from CloudFlare Flexible SSL but when I use https it doesn't seem to load image and CSS assets.

I already disabled hotlink protection.

Here are some images to illustrate the difference:

**Using https**: http://gyazo.com/ef6ccb13c2c8f3f797dcb2d947a772cb

**Not using https**: http://gyazo.com/be277259e0dcc8e395316b573de12935

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the browsers console shows lots of messages like this:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://hornetvault.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.hornetvault.com/templates/fresh/assets/css/styles.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Which means you try to load resources using `http://` inside a `https://` site and these resources get blocked. You need to load these resources by `https://` too. You might try to simple use `//` instead of explicitly given `http://` or `https://` in your URLs, in which case it will simply use the same scheme (http or https) as the page itself.